# Multiple BizTalk custom pipeline components in the same assembly

Tags: components, biztalk

The question is <strike>entirely described in the title</strike>: is it possible to have multiple **components** in the same .NET assembly. All examples I've seen so far had a single custom pipeline component per assembly.
Microsoft.BizTalk.Pipeline.Components.dll would be a good example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is Yes. As long as each component coded and deployed properly, they all show up in VS.NET designer and are usable.

Answer (score 0):

Sean, are you asking if it is possible to have more then one custom pipeline per assembly? If so then yes. Whether or not it is a good idea is more organizational then anything.

Personally we generally decide by our deployment needs or desires. Do we want to be able to deploy the pipelines piecemeal or by a certain customer where multiple pipelines makes sense.

Comment: Andrew,

The question was about components, not pipelines themselves. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Sean

Comment: Ah, missed that. I'm glad you found your answer though.